User profile present on one application but not another on the same environment
I have two web applications in a SharePoint 2013 environment.
Web Application - A
Web Application - B
I need to assign permission to one user on a site that is on Web Application B. When I try to assign permission on any site of Web Application - B, the user is not displaying there.
When I try to assign permission to the same user on any site on web application - A, it works fine.
When I tried through Central Admin > Manage Profile Service > User Profile Service Application > People > Manage User Profiles > Find Profile, the User name shows there... so the profile obviously exists.
What is the reason for this?

Consider upgrading your SP2013 environment to a version that is still supported--2016 at minimum, but preferably 2019 or 2022 (or move to SharePoint Online).

Are you using different authentication for that webapplication? Sound's like some sort of corruption to me.
